# Formula to Concatenate Visible Cells, Remove Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

TL;DR: I need a formula to concatenate visible cells, remove duplicates, and add a ", " in between values.

I have a spreadsheet that I have macros filtering all the time and running data pulls.

Row 3 holds formulas that pull specific metrics out of my data set in A6:S16627.

One of the cells in Row 3 calls a VBA script to run that concatenates visible cells, and returns a value with duplicates removed.

For example, if the data was 100, 100, 101, 102, 101, it would return "100, 101, 102."

My difficulty is, this script does not refresh effectively when a parent macro runs through the autofilter and copy+paste's row 3 onto another sheet.

Is there a way to replicate the script below as an excel formula, that works with the scenario I provided above?

```
Public Function MakeList(myRange As Range)
Dim c As Range, MyDict As Object

    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In myRange
        If Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False Then
            MyDict.Add c.Value, 1
        End If
    Next c

    MakeList = Join(MyDict.keys, ", ")

End Function
```

Thank you for any help you might be able to provide.

EDIT:

Here's the second code interacting with the code above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub VBAFilterCopyPaste()
    Dim cell As Range 'loop range
    Dim Rng As Range 'range for unique values

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet

    Dim lRow As Long 'last row in RegionSummary
    Dim i As Integer 'counter

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("WAP")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("HCAsummary")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("NamedRange")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'reset autofilter
    ws1.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter

    'autofilter on project selected
    ws1.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws2.Range("Q6")

    'copy Column B in Table2 to named Range I1
    ws1.Range("B5:B16627").SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy 'extend 16627 this if needed
    ws3.Range("i1").PasteSpecial

    'Remove duplicates for unique values
    ws3.Columns("I:I").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    'set range for loop and sort
    Set Rng = ws3.Range("i2:i" & ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "i").End(xlUp).Row)
    Rng.Sort Key1:=ws3.Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending

    lRow = 11 'set current last row for start of HCASummary

    'loop to copy row 3 from ws1 to ws2

    For Each cell In Rng
        'increment last row
        i = i + 1

        With ws1
            .ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value
            .Range("A3:S3").Copy
            ws2.Range("a" & lRow + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

    Next

    'goto ws2.Range A11
    Application.Goto ws2.Range("A11")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not call the function from your other script?

Comment: @RyanWildry would you be able to add that into the above script where you see it belonging? I'm not sure what you would have that replace.

Comment: @SJR It generates errors and I can't seem to get it functional.

Comment: You'd have to post the rest of the code for us to work that out.

Comment: @RyanWildry and user3598756 - Both of your script fixes functional as expected. I tested each of them with my current script pull and both suffer the same fate as my script above where they don't update when filters change. You have to F2+Enter to recalculate the output. Is there some way to have it re-run with any sheet changes? Maybe that might solve my overlying problem.

Comment: You can try adding it in the WorkSheet_Change Event

Comment: See updated post for the other code.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, I cleaned up this function. There were a few issues. As I mentioned just ignoring the errors created from a duplicate isn't a good idea. Instead check to see if the value is in the dictionary first.

Additionally I added some error handling, and made the function return a String value which I believe is what you want.

```
Public Function MakeList(ByVal myRange As Range) As String
On Error GoTo Errhand:

    Dim c       As Range
    Dim MyDict  As Object: Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each c In myRange
        If Not Rows(c.Row).Hidden Then
            If Not MyDict.exists(c.Value2) Then MyDict.Add c.Value2, 1
        End If
    Next

    MakeList = Join(MyDict.keys, ", ")

 cleanExit:
    Set MyDict = Nothing
    Set c = Nothing
    Exit Function

Errhand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    GoTo cleanExit
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Unfortunately the code doesn't return any concatenated values when run. An easy way to test for yourself is make any data set, say type 1-25 in Column A, in Column B1, type =MakeList(A1:A25) and it should concatenate all values. At the moment, I don't think the code runs.

Comment: Ryan, think you are just missing a Not in your If clause.

Comment: I see it, when adding to the Dict. I added it just now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually grasp what you mean with

```
this script does not refresh effectively when a parent macro runs through the autofilter and copy+paste's row 3 onto another sheet.
```

you may want to elaborate on it

in the meanwhile you could test this little refactoring:

```
Public Function MakeList(myRange As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim c As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each c In myRange
            If Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False Then .Item(c.Value) = c.Value
        Next c
        MakeList = Join(.keys, ", ")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Let me try and clarify. I have another script that loops through all filters on Sheet1! and copies A3:S3 from Sheet1 and pastes them on Sheet 2. A3:S3 on Sheet1 have formulas in them that pull specific data out of my table. Each time the script filters to the next filter item, the formulas in row 3 recalculate, providing new values to copy over to Sheet2. Three of the cells in A3:S3 are reliant on the above script updating. There is an error in the macros now that cause the above mentioned macro to concatenate everything, as opposed to specific data in the filtered range.

Comment: My original hope was to see if a formula could accomplish the same thing as the scripts provided by me, you, and Ryan above. I'm assuming that Excel formulas can't handle such a request, and thus becomes why VBA was built.